# How to NOT include parent directories when using zip command?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, find, exec

I need to:

1. Traverse a directory and find all sub-sub-folders created for > X days ago
2. Zip the content of these folders inside the sub-sub-folder and remove the
   previous content

**Example of file strucutre from the beginning:**

```
root_folder:
    sub-dir (many of these):
        sub-sub-dir (many of these):
            content1 (can be file or folder)
            content2 (can be file or folder)
            content3 (can be file or folder)
```

**Example of file strucutre after command is finished:**

```
root_folder:
    sub-dir:
        sub-sub-dir:
            zipfile.zip
```

**BUT!** **I do not want to include the whole folder structure** (sub-dir/sub-sub-dir) in the zip file. I only want the zip file to look like this:

```
zip_file:
    content1 (no matter if it is a file or a folder with content in it)
    content2 (no matter if it is a file or a folder with content in it)
    content3 (no matter if it is a file or a folder with content in it)
```

Instead of:

```
zip_file:
    sub-dir:
        sub-sub-dir:
            content1
            content2
            content3
```

The command I have used this far solves everything but the folder structure part... It looks something like this (I do not have the exact command in front of me right now. I'll probably update it tomorrow.

```
find * -mindepth X -maxdepth X -mtime +10 -exec zip -r -m \{}/zipfilename {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`.

From the manpage:

```
   -execdir command ;

   -execdir command {} +
          Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the  subdirec‐
          tory  containing  the  matched  file,  which is not normally the
          directory in which you started find.  This a  much  more  secure
          method  for invoking commands, as it avoids race conditions dur‐
          ing resolution of the paths to the matched files.  As  with  the
          -exec action, the `+' form of -execdir will build a command line
          to process more than one matched file, but any given  invocation
          of command will only list files that exist in the same subdirec‐
          tory.  If you use this option, you must ensure that  your  $PATH
          environment  variable  does  not  reference  `.';  otherwise, an
          attacker can run any commands they like by leaving an  appropri‐
          ately-named  file in a directory in which you will run -execdir.
          The same applies to having entries in $PATH which are  empty  or
          which  are  not absolute directory names.  If find encounters an
          error, this can sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some pend‐
          ing  commands  may  not  be run at all. The result of the action
          depends on whether the  +  or  the  ;  variant  is  being  used;
          -execdir  command  {} + always returns true, while -execdir com‐
          mand {} ; returns true only if command returns 0.
```

For example:

```
$ find sub-dir 
sub-dir
sub-dir/sub-sub-dir
sub-dir/sub-sub-dir/content3
sub-dir/sub-sub-dir/content1
sub-dir/sub-sub-dir/content1/file
sub-dir/sub-sub-dir/content2

$ find sub-dir/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -execdir zip -r -m {}/zipped {} \;
```

...

```
$ unzip -l sub-dir/sub-sub-dir/content1/zipped.zip                                
Archive:  sub-dir/sub-sub-dir/content1/zipped.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-05-17 17:23   content1/
        4  2017-05-17 17:23   content1/file
---------                     -------
        4                     2 files
```

Of course, if you don't want *any* paths in your zip file, you can just pass `-j` (or `--junk-paths`) to store the just the files.

Comment: Thank you very very very very much! execdir was exactly what I wanted. Now there is just 1 minor problem left... :)

If I want to name the zipped file to something more dynamic like: sub-dir_sub-sub-dir.zip, is that possible somehow?

One more time; thank you very much for the help! That definitely saved me some time.

Comment: That starts to get complicated :) 
I think the key would be to pass a script with `-execdir` instead of a command. Spawning a new shell you'll be able to check `$PWD` and manipulate it based on that. For example, `-execdir bash -c 'zipname=${PWD//\//-}; zip -r $zipname ...'` (though IMO it's cleaner to actually make a script than use `bash -c`).